# angularjs shows injector error even though all dependencies are mentioned

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I am new angular. I am writing a simple angular application. I have created a module and a controller for that module and a factory. I added the dependencies to the controller but, I am getting an injector error. I just don't understand where I am going wrong.

This is my angular code :

```
var app = angular.module("bookApp",[]);
app.config(['$interpolateProvider',function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
}]);;app.controller("mainController",["$scope", "$http", "titles",function($scope, $http, titles){
    $scope.titles = [{}];
    titles.getTitles();
}]);
app.factory("titles",["$scope","$http",function($scope, $http){
    var getTitles = function(){
        $http.get("http://localhost:8000/getTitles")
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.titles = response.data;
        });
    }

    var addTitle = function(){
        var data = $.param({
            json: JSON.stringify({
                title: $scope.book.bookname
            })
        });
        $http.post("http://localhost:8000/addTitle",data).success(function(response, status){
            $scope.titles = response.data;
        });
    }
    return{
        getTitles: getTitles
    }

}]);
```

My html:

```
<body ng-app="bookApp">
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <table id="recordTable" ng-controller="mainController">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>S.No</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="title in titles">
                        <td>{[{title.id}]}</td>
                        <td>{[{title.bookname}]}</td>
                    </tr>   
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

I get the following error:

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20titles
```

I don't understand the problem here. The "titles" service is there but it still gives injector error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you had injected `$scope` inside a factory, which isn't available to inject inside a factory. You have to remove to the `$scope` dependency from the factory Dependency array an factory code.

> If you look at the definition of factory/service, they are sigletone
>   object which are applicable throughout the application to provide
>   common functionality between different components of angular
>   application.

You should remove the scope from factory thoroughly like below, and the major change I made in factory is returned promise object of `$http.get` method.

**Factory**

```
app.factory("titles",["$http",function($http){
    var getTitles = function(){
        return $http.get("http://localhost:8000/getTitles")
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }

    var addTitle = function(book){
        var data = $.param({
            json: JSON.stringify({
                title: book.bookname
            })
        });
        return $http.post("http://localhost:8000/addTitle",data).success(function(response, status){
            return response.data;
        });
    }
    return{
        getTitles: getTitles,
        addTitle: addTitle
    }

}]);
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller("mainController",["$scope", "$http","titles",
   function($scope, $http, titles){
     //$scope.titles = [{}];
     titles.getTitles().then(function(data){
        $scope.titles = data;
     });
   }
]);
```

Comment: You're still passing `$scope` to the factory